# Android ImageView Positioning For Different Density Screen

Tags: android

I have an Imageview on the right side of the screen inside a frame layout.I have 9 patched the image.When position the image , i see a change in position of image inside imageview when i see in same device with different densities.What should be done to avoid the same?

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/characterimageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"                
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/characterimageview"
            android:visibility="visible" />
       </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `android:layout_width`, `android:layout_height`, and positioning attributes (margins, padding, etc) as fixed values in `dp` (density independent pixels) units. The sizes and positions you define will look the same on every screen.
Something like this, for instance:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp" // notice the change here
    android:layout_height="50dp" // and here
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/characterimageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"                
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/characterimageview"
        android:visibility="visible" />
   </FrameLayout>
```

should work...

Comment: It didnt work as expected.Well As per Android Developer Site it is not recommended to set dp values to width and height of a layout.Please suggest any other method.